# how to minimize a flowchart

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I have managed to make some flow charts (vertical chart and pie chart) but I have a problem,I want to minimize the charts because are occupying almost my entire page.

Here is what I have done:

```
<form action="listacumparaturi" method="get">
  <canvas width="2200" height="2200" id="myCanvas"></canvas>

  <script>
  var x = "${sumC}";
  var y = "${sumG}";
  var z = "${sumP}";
  var w = "${sumCa}";
  total = "${sumT}";
  var vertical = {
    Calorii: x,
    Grasimi: y,
    Proteine: z,
    Carbohidrati: w
  };
  var data = Object.keys(vertical);
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  total = "${sumT}";
  color = ['orange', 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];
  start = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
    ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, x, 10, -(vertical[data[i]]));
    ctx.font = "13px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(data[i], (i * 60) + 51, x * 1.015);
    ctx.fillText((1 * i), 20, ((32 * -i) + 920));
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(600, 150);
    ctx.arc(600, 150, 150, start, start +
      (Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total)), false);
    ctx.lineTo(600, 150);
    ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
    ctx.fill();
    start += Math.PI * 2 * (vertical[data[i]] / total);
  }
  </script>
</form>
```

Does anyone know how can I minimize this flow charts?I want the values to be the same but the pictures be minimized.

Here you can find a preview: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Meayrb

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated the scale in the code pen URL ..Added total while calculating vertical bar height -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Meayrb

```
                ctx.fillRect((i * 60) + 50, 300, 10,( -(vertical[data[i]])*100)/total);
                ctx.font = "9px Arial";
                ctx.fillText(data[i], (i * 60) + 51, 742);
                ctx.fillText((700 * i), 30, (((70) * -i) + 300));
```

And scale on y-axxis and bar height are dynamic now and adjust automatically based on your inputs.
Hope this is helpful for you

Comment: Yes is helpful, also another problem that I see is that the scale of numbers from the left side is not corresponding with the vertical chart.For example a:1080 and the blue line is above 1080.

Comment: No ..I think it is adjusting to the value..for testing i changed first value to 1400.Please find the codepen URL - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Meayrb

Comment: Yes,I saw, my bad, :( another thing that I want is to display only the 1400 value , I don't want another values above (2100,etc), Could you please take a look?

Comment: add condition to allow values less than 2100..added in codepen 
if(vertical[data[i]] < 2100){.
Please this helpful..can mark this question as answered

Comment: I just gave a value - more than 2100 ,can check it once now 
var vertical = {
            a: 1400,
            b: 2100,
            c: 84,
            d :49
            
          };
you just want to display bars less than 2100 correct???

Comment: No, I want the scale numbers, on the left side (0,700,1400,2100) to be displayed only the max number.Ex : if a :700 and it is max value I want the scale to be displayed from 2 numbers : 0-700 ,i don;t want the next numbers 1400 and 2100

Comment: updated codepen ..now the scale gets adjusted to max value

Comment: Please mark this as answered and start new question..if your next question is other than the asked in this question